# Substitute multiple periods in all column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, substitution

I have the following data.frame.

```
 df = data.frame(a.dfs.56=c(rep("a",8), rep("b",5), rep("c",7), rep("d",10)), 
      b.fqh.28=rnorm(30, 6, 2), 
      c.34.2.fgs=rnorm(30, 12, 3.5), 
      d.tre.19.frn=rnorm(30, 8, 3)
      )
```

How can I substitute all periods "." in the column names to have them become dashes "-"?

I am aware of options like `check.names=FALSE` when using `read.table` or `data.frame`, but in this case, I cannot use this.

I have also tried variations of the following posts, but they did not work for me.

[Specifying column names in a data.frame changes spaces to "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411201/specifying-column-names-in-a-data-frame-changes-spaces-to)

[How can I use gsub in multiple specific column in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963214/how-can-i-use-gsub-in-multiple-specific-column-in-r)

[R gsub column names in all data frames within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715958/r-gsub-column-names-in-all-data-frames-within-a-list)

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309876/r-how-to-replace-in-a-string You have to use it for column names instead of a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` for name replacement

```
names(df) <- gsub(".", "-", names(df), fixed=TRUE)
```

Note that you need `fixed=TRUE` because normally `gsub` expects regular expressions and `.` is a special regular expression character.

But be aware that `-` is a non-standard character for variable names. If you try to use those columns with functions that use non-standard evaluation, you will need to surround the names in back-ticks to use them. For example

```
dplyr::filter(df, `a-dfs-56`=="a")
```

Comment: Oh, that's really cool! That's why gsub did not work for me :) Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

`gsub("\\.", "-", names(df))` is the regex (regular expressions) way. The `.` is a special symbol in regex that means "match any single character". That's why the `fixed = TRUE` argument is included in MrFlick's answer.

The `\\` (escape) tells R that we wan't the literal period and not the special symbol that it represents.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you so much for explaining - Syl.